# How to toggle a class with React inside a map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, toggle

I would like to toggle a class when I click on an element of a list but I only can add a class, not remove it.
Several answers can be selected and therefore have the "active" className.

I try before with toggle() method:

```
const ChoiceList = (props) => {

  const { choices } = props

  // ----------First method with toggle-----------------

  const answers = document.querySelectorAll(".answer")
  console.log("Answers array :", answers)

  answers.forEach(answer => {

    answer.addEventListener("click", () => {

      answer.classList.toggle("active")
      
    })

  })

  const choicesItemsJsx = choices.map(({id, value, weight}, index) => {
    return <li
      className="answer"
      id={id}
      key={index}
      onClick={() => {}}
    >{value}</li>
  })

  return <ul>{choicesItemsJsx}</ul>
}

ChoiceList.defaultProps = {
  choises: []
}
```

With this one, I can neither add nor remove my class
And then with add() and remove():

```
  // ----------Second method with add & remove----------------
  
  const answers = document.querySelectorAll(".answer")
  console.log("Answers array :", answers)

  answers.forEach(answer => {

    answer.addEventListener("click", () => {
      
      if (answer.classList.contains("active")) {
        answer.classList.remove("active")
      } else {
        answer.classList.add("active")
      }

    })

  })
```

It doesn't work too, I can neither add nor remove my class.
Yet in doing this, I can at least add my class for each element of my list, why ?

```
  const answers = document.querySelectorAll(".answer")
  console.log("Answers array :", answers)

  answers.forEach(answer => {

    answer.addEventListener("click", () => {
      
      if (answer.classList.contains("active")) {
        return
      } else {
        answer.classList.add("active")
      }
         
    })

  })
```

I think, it's better to use a state for my objective, but before, I would like to know why it doesn't work with this code.

Thank you

Comment: You should almost never modify DOM directly in React. Please use state instead. All of these `querySelectorAll` run before or in the middle of creating DOM nodes.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I was doubting myself...
Is it due to asynchronicity ?

Comment: It's due to the fact that react components handle creating the DOM in the background. When the component renders for the first time the DOM isn't even created yet for example.

Comment: Ok, it's logic. This is what react was created for. Thanks

Comment: You might want have a look at [the introductory documentation for React](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/thinking-in-react).